# Infer first element of a tuple and use it to type the second element

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type a function that is supposed to remap values of an object to something else.

Here's how it looks like:

```js
const result = mapValue(
  {
    foo: "a",
    bar: 10,
    baz: true,
  },
  [
    ["foo", (value) => `thing ${value}`],
    ["bar", (value) => value - 1],
  ]
);

result; // { foo: "thing a", bar: 9 }
```

I'm struggling to type the second argument of this function, which is basically a matrix with the key you want to remap, and a callback that's going to compute the new value.

The current type declaration I have is not able to narrow the type of the argument that is passed to the mapper callbacks. So for instance, for the mapper `["foo", (value) => value]`, `value` is going to be `string | number | boolean` where it should be narrowed only to `string`

Here's a basic "not very type safe" draft:

```js
declare function mapValue<T, TKey extends keyof T, TResult>(
  obj: T,
  mapping: Array<[TKey, (x: T[TKey]) => TResult]>,
): Record<typeof mapping[number][0], ReturnType<typeof mapping[number][1]>>;
```

I tried to progressively infer the `mapping` argument with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), but typescript doesn't seem to be able to infer properly from `TMapped[i][0]`:

```js
declare function mapValue<T, const TMapping>(
  obj: T,
  mapping: {
    [i in keyof TMapping]: TMapping[i] extends [infer key, any] ? [TMapping[i][0], (value: T[key]) => unknown] : never
  },
): "todo";
```

Playground link if you want to give it a shot:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsoAHANSgmRAB4AVAGnloGkQBPeEADwxFWADO8ANbsciJo1oAlEAOQQMAPgAUAKHjwcAIwBWALkkbCJYllQBzQwEEYMKG2oBtFu0Yquh2i9ZsAugCU8AC8Skyy8op+SvRqAYayYDgwwNQYbMQg4ibEZpZOqMgE2iAwfk4ADH6MshjIMKi0GTTpmdlEueYWBUUlZU4AjNFKANxqakmoAhjwcJEzwTnklCDqmgDexpqIODiGAERQ+7GamtqwhgMVJ6fnAF6GGDBUNwC+N05b8E77OzjH8BUADcKFQgqF4AADDAACy68AAJOsQStXpDql8fucYADgaCQOCwiiqPAALTwIY3PxxMZqOYKDAjeAAemZ8HWSF2B1h8KOjGxhgAnPBXkA

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/NB1Pxw

Comment: @Filly please describe what's going on at that link, how it addresses the question (presumably the OP cares about their input format), and what information you're seeking from posting as a comment (as opposed to posting it in an answer).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w21KrW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @Filly's answer is pretty much what I need. I would have preferred to use a tuple but according to jcalz it is not yet possible in typescript to infer arguments of a tuple in a union. But, if inference doesn't work only if in a union, is there a way to bypass this and still get inference to work with a tuple for this particular use case? or am i just doomed to use an object like in Filly's answer?

Comment: You can annotate the callback parameters, or use an object (presumably a `Partial` one), or go help fix the bug in TS I linked (or wait for it to be fixed, but that could be a long wait).  Whether any of those could be called "doomed" is a matter of opinion.  How would you like to proceed with an answer to this question?

Comment: Ok, thank you. An object should be fine.

Comment: So then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mb1d9N) work for you?  If so I'll write up an answer (explaining why the tuple approach is currently untenable); otherwise what am I missing?

Comment: sure, this approach is fine. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your current input format with the following call signature

```
declare function mapValue<T, U extends KFPairs<T>>(
  obj: T,
  mapping: U[],
): { [V in U as V[0]]: ReturnType<V[1]> };

type KFPairs<T> = { [K in keyof T]: [K, (value: T[K]) => any] }[keyof T]

const result = mapValue(
  {
    foo: "a",
    bar: 10,
    baz: true,
  },
  [
    ["foo", (value: string) => `thing ${value}`], 
    ["bar", (value: number) => value - 1],
  ]
);

result; 
/* const result: {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
} */
```

but you need to annotate your callback parameters (`value` above) for this to work, due to an outstanding bug in TypeScript reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#55632](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55632).  [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) that are also [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) apparently don't get discriminated soon enough for [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of callback parameters to happen.

I'm not going to describe in detail how the above works, because you're not going to use this solution.  In brief, though:

- `KFPairs<T>` is a *distributive object type* (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) that produces a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of tuple types `[K, F<K>]` where `K` is each key of `K` and `F<K>` is a function accepting `T[K]` as an input.
- The output type is a [key remapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) that extracts the key `V[0]` and the function return type `ReturnType<V[1]>` from each element `V` of the union `U` of `mapping` array element types.

---

If you want contextual typing of the callback parameters, you'll need to abandon tuples, until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#55632 is fixed.  For now the easiest approach is to switch from an array of tuples to a single object type whose keys are some subset of the keys of `T` and whose values are the appropriate functions from `T[K]` to some return type.  Like this:

```
declare function mapValue<T extends object, U extends object>(
  obj: T,
  mapping: {
    [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? (value: T[K]) => U[K] : never
  },
): U;
```

Here the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` corresponds to type of the input `obj`, and `U` corresponds to the expected output type.  The type of `mapping` is therefore a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `U` where each property at key `K` is a function accepting `T[K]` and returning `U[K]`.  Conceptually you really want to be sure that `U` only contains keys from `T` (it is allowed to have fewer keys but not extra ones), but that restriction can't be directly encoded onto a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) for `U`.  Instead what is happening is that, if `U` has a key not in `T`, then the expected property type of `mapping` will be [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), so you'll get an error if you try to use that.

Here's how it works:

```
const result = mapValue(
  {
    foo: "a",
    bar: 10,
    baz: true,
  },
  {
    foo: (value) => `thing ${value}`,
    bar: (value) => value - 1,      
  }
);

result; 
/* const result: {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
} */
```

Looks good.  The compiler produces a value of the desired type, and the callback parameters `value` are inferred correctly.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4CgkkAXATxmQGkAxABRAzSgB4AVAPiQF48kBtSkgzAkAawikA9gDMkrALoAufpQA0SABQA3EABsArhGWsB8gJTdOIYKXlIAvn3FTZCwkgAmEeLpBpk0vrA8MQYkiJgIDAAanqGbOoAqkgQAB7EEMAeUEg09IwsHOwa7kSSAEYAVsaqpUiRMDDCWMqJfPK1RGbKuPzRQiLJIDnRfAAM8kpIAEoQxPpowKzkEMyjAIzynPYA3Pju8OFQxEj+UPq6JzwNsQYQJUREBI+P0pKSygBEIJ+dL0jlPzKdZjP4vQEAL2UxDQhjBDnhfDqRAA9CikFJ9AByfxIfRQZokfQwXTQJBQSQYyT6JDACAQDwkSnWYCSYggDIkAAWyB0dyQ8D0ukB8FESDgaHAAIgukkAHdkUg0Z5DEykFziMQYFBFGisBhiFz9OUAHSHMAosAYeBoSQU6TEFHLCgAZRtGBgjowUHO0BRAFZ-QA2ADMACZFXxPm9JL9NHzDMpjphgFgLFxOAADQ2EgAkuATEHsmY6kc+gLQce0cSMtP0YHKEDQ6c4haQAFokJt4fJ3GY9u4zhdiDslejejGvjnU0gfuoK8oAJwOdwogBUAqOJyHlx6isn5JhzT2-wBQLrDabJ4cSDXKP2+3s+1AkFgCGQKCqeH2RC8Pj8ARBCEYQRFEtzxKwKTpJk2RIBUlTeMQSRQRkWQ5PBiHFHU8E1HUDRNKme6ngIAxiBIMhIIkUyCGkqGwc4FGQQA-PGNbGKYLaUaYSDKHSWhNnU9h-N0lEDkQhzAMcpzQMO3D1GBNYPI8zz-Ae3y-IqC5dqCmkgFCJCwhA8JCXUKkvAe1Z3Jx2ZcnmBY1sW8JEFplmGJxbadusxl9mJ0nnJco7KhO7xTrZM5zmeaBLiuqIbhJUk7sQRGqSFh4plg17guewD1o2aDXvYt73vg9hAA)